# What does the $4\pi k_{m}$ mean in Ampere's law?

Tags: magnetic-fields

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) Ampere's law is written

$$ \oint_{C} B \cdot dl = \mu_{0}I_{enc}$$

and in [this resource by Kirby Morgan about Ampere's law](http://www.physnet.org/modules/pdf_modules/m138.pdf) it is written as

$$ \oint_{C} B \cdot dl = 4\pi k_{m}I_{C}$$

What exactly is $4\pi k_{m}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparison, $4\pi k_m= \mu_0$ (the greek letter mu).
So, $$k_m=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi},$$
which is in analogy to the constant in Coulomb's law
$$k_e=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}.$$